# Why TypeScript compiler doesn't handle correctly nested object filtering?

Tags: typescript

Maybe generic TypeScript question.
Consider such a simple filtering code:

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  name?: string;
}

const users: User[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'aaa' },
  { id: 2  },
  { id: 3, name: 'bbb' },
];

users
  .filter(user => Boolean(user.name))
  // Object is possibly 'undefined'... why?
  .map(user => console.log(user.name.length));
```

I have filter out `undefined` in the `filter` block, but compiler persist says `Object is possibly 'undefined'`.

Could someone explain why TypeScript behave such things? 
Any good workaround of this.

> NOTE: I want to use `strictNullChecks` option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

TypeScript is not smart enough to infer that your filter implies that `user.name` now cannot be falsey.

Apparently, there's a specific overload for `Array#filter` that deals with type guards:

```
// From lib.es5.d.ts
interface Array<T> {
  // ...
  filter<S extends T>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[];
  // ...
}
```

Which means that if you pass a type-guard function to filter, the resulting array will be of the narrower type!

```
interface ConfirmedNameUser extends User {
  name: string; // no ?
}

// snip

  .filter((user): user is ConfirmedNameUser => Boolean(user.name)
  // no longer errors, type of user is ConfirmedNameUser and not User
  .map(user => console.log(user.name.length));
```

**[Playground Example](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnLAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANz7lxUQD8Z6YUoA5owF9cuBAHsQXZBUxR0ZDNADaAXWQBeZIqbZCpZAEYANM1ZkA5HEtnkAw9t1kATAVv3iZAMzGQLCOZoB1q7KjLjS0OhMAHQwwAA2kFAAFEnhUACUZGmE6MgAShAAjhTAUBBEADwKUAB86nUAQqKicRBwIKkyUT6s6elMAPQDyADyNABWEAhgOcgADqLo6MA0cQCeyGYUIEQQsSDlZlHHyADuABZrbNFUcHOdWGp1YhItEFFxorwPUN2+HxAQLwwOc+owgA)**

---

Alternatively, a less involved solution is to tell it to trust you that it's not `undefined` using the `!` non-null assertion operator:

```
.map(user => console.log(user.name!.length));
```

Note that you should use the `!` operation sparingly and only when you are 100% sure that TypeScript is being overzealous and that "you know better". The `!` merely silences the warning, it does not do any sort of runtime check (as opposed to the proposed `?.` and `??` operators).

Using `!` where you should not might lead to runtime TypeErrors.

Comment: Yeah, using `!` Is one of the quick fixes for that, though. I used to have a terrible experience with this, so now I'm looking for a different solution.

Comment: Your only other solution, (AFAIK) is to actualy check that `user.name` is not defined.

Comment: @mitsuruog It seems like I was wrong and that type narrowing via custom guards works with filter! I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) as your filter callback (put `arg is T` as the return type of the function), so that calls after the filter have the correct input type:

```
users
  .filter((user): user is Required<User> => !!user.name)
  .map(user => console.log(user.name.length));
```

In this case you can use the built-in mapped-type `Required<T>` since only the name is optional. But you could also use a type like `{ name: string }` if you prefer.

Comment: I love this short name solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to go here is to inform the compiler that your filter acts as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
interface NamedUser extends User {
  name: string;
}

users
  .filter((user: User): user is NamedUser => Boolean(user.name)) //annotated callback
  .map(user => console.log(user.name.length)); // okay now
```

I've introduced a type called `NamedUser` which is the same as `User` but where the `name` property is definitely present.  Then I've annotated the callback to `users.filter()` as a type guard.  This causes the compiler to select the following overload of `filter()` [defined in the standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1310):

```
interface Array<T> {
  filter<S extends T>(
    callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => value is S, 
    thisArg?: any
  ): S[];
}
```

So the return value of `users.filter()` is now `NamedUser[]` instead of just `User[]`.  And therefore the subsequent `map()` call works as expected.

There is a [suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069) to have the compiler recognize boolean-valued callbacks like `x => !!x` or `x => Boolean(x)` as type guards.  If that suggestion or something like it is ever implemented, your original code might be able to compile with no warning as-is.  But for now you have to annotate it manually.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If you have some code that uses named users, I suggest to create a type for them:

```
type NamedUser = Required<User>
```

Then, you could use this kind of code:

```
const namedUsers = users.filter(user => Boolean(user.name)) as NamedUser[]
namedUsers.forEach(user => console.log(user.name.length));
```

Or with the type guard suggested by Aaron and jcalz:

```
function isNamedUser(user: User): user is NamedUser {
    return Boolean(user.name)
}

users
  .filter(isNamedUser)
  .forEach(user => console.log(user.name.length));
```

Comment: is there sort of generic solution to this where I can pass the array and fields and same results?